# Windows phone 8 app Code to find location using shake accelerometer

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to create code to find the location on map using the shake accelerometer on Windows phone 8 emulator.

I use reverse geocoding for displaying the location using a button, but i have no idea how to display the location using the shake sensor, can anyone help or give me links to somewhere I can learn to create code for this feature.

```
 private void ReverseGeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            if (e.Result.Count > 0)
            {
                MapAddress address = e.Result[0].Information.Address;
                CurrentLocTextBlock.Text = "Current Location: ";;
                AddressTextBlock.Text = address.City + ", " + address.State;
            }
        }
    }
```